# How to convert non-numeric values to blank for use in case statement?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, compiler-errors, data-conversion, sqldatatypes

I am working on the following query:

```
declare @start date = '06/01/2016';
declare @end date   = '07/31/2017';

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------
-- Pull all claims with paid date in range parameter
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
------------------------------------------------

if object_id('LA_Temp.dbo.Item19') is not null drop table LA_Temp.dbo.Item19
select distinct
c.claimid,  
c.formtype,
c.facilitycode + c.billclasscode as BillType, 
case when primaryclaimid = '' and resubclaimid = '' then 'Clean' else 'Other' end as CleanClaim,
    -- DHHClaimtype 04 needs to be broken out based on provider specialty and location
    Case when c.formtype = '1500' and cd.location = 21 and ps.specialtycode in ('05','22','1T','1F','30','1C') then '04-Hospitalist'
    when c.formtype = '1500' then '04-Other'
    else '  '
end as DHHClaimtype,
c.status,
c.totalpaid, 
e.phystate as MemberState,
e.phycounty as MemberParish,
pc.ParishCode as MemberParishCode,
con.contracted as NetworkProvider,
reject
into LA_Temp.dbo.Item19
from claim c
inner join member m on c.memid = m.memid
inner join entity e on m.entityid = e.entid
left join LA_Temp.dbo.ParishCodes pc on e.phycounty = pc.Parish
inner join contract con on c.contractid = con.contractid
inner join provider p on c.provid = p.provid
inner join provspecialty ps on p.provid = ps.provid and ps.spectype = 
'PRIMARY'
inner join claimdetail cd on c.claimid = cd.claimid and cd.claimline = 1 -- just pull the first line to 
grab the location code, exclude any location codes with non-numeric values
where c.paiddate between @start and @end
and c.status in ('PAID','DENIED');

-- add the claim types to the table
EXECUTE LA_Temp.[dbo].[USP_LA_SetDHHClaimType] @Table = 'Item19';
```

The problem exists in the first case statement.  Specifically here:

```
and cd.location = 21
```

Upon further investigation of the claimdetail (cd) table, I have found that column cd.location (datatype = int) has 4 values ('H', 'U8', 'A', 'OH') which are onviously not numeric. I would like to convert these values to blanks (if possible, not sure if blanks (' ') are compatible with int datatype) or zeros if blanks will not work.  Due to the NonNumeric values, I am getting the following error (which is to be expected):

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'H ' to data type int.

I am aware that I can exclude these records in either the join clause or in a where statement such as:

```
Where cd.location not in ('H', 'U8', 'A', 'OH')
```

However, I want to keep the records that these values are tied to, I just want the cd.location value to be blank when it is one of these 4 values.  Can someone show me how I can keep these records, by converting cd.location to ' ' when cd.location in ('H', 'U8', 'A', 'OH').

Comment: It looks like you know how to add a `CASE` statement already, since you have one. When you tried to add a `CASE` for your new requirement, what happened?

Comment: Nested case statement possible?  Running query now with the following replacement of:  

and cd.location = 21

and Case When IsNumeric(cd.location) = 0 Then '' Else cd.location End = 21

Comment: I should think nested case statements are possible, but I don't fully understand why it would be necessary. Your syntax of using joined "and" statements would probably be fine: `CASE WHEN (existing booleans) AND cd.location in ('H', 'U8', 'A', 'OH') THEN ''`.

Comment: There may be some nuance to this I don't understand though, and of course I don't know/understand your data. Consider formulating a (cut-down) SQL Fiddle so that readers can see the output you are getting, and trial some things to add the clause you want.

Comment: and cd.location = 21 was causing varchar to integer conversion error

Comment: ^ If you are getting an error, you definitely need to be able to show what you have in a simple way. Edit your question with the _exact_ query you now have, show the data you are operating on (or a cut down dataset) and supply a fiddle or other way in which people can see an [mcve].

Comment: The nested case statement worked (it prevented the conversion error listed in the original post).  Instead of just using "and cd.location = 21" I nested a case to prevent the error which is as follows: "and Case When IsNumeric(cd.location) = 0 Then '' 
    Else cd.location End = 21"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I don't know why the light bulb when off in my head right after I posted this.  Perhaps seeing it written out or typing it triggered something,  I never did a nested case before.

Comment: Yup, the [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) helped you!

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that if `cd.location` is a `varchar`, then your comparison would have been invalid (as the database pointed out). If you are storing a mix of string and numeric data in here, then a simplified clause would involve quotes: `cd.location = '21'`. You can of course stick with what you have, but if you want to simplify (e.g. to improve a poorly-performing query) then this may be worth looking at in the future.

Comment: Halfer, this is an excellent idea.  I would rather keep the values and your suggestion would do that.  Thank you!  Small little things like single quotes making all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it...

Again we are focusing on the first case statement in the originally posted query:

```
    case
    -- DHHClaimtype 04 needs to be broken out based on provider specialty and location
    When c.formtype = '1500' and cd.location = 21 and ps.specialtycode in ('05','22','1T','1F','30','1C') 
    Then '04-Hospitalist'
    When c.formtype = '1500' 
    Then '04-Other'
    else '  '
 end as DHHClaimtype,
```

Changed to:

```
    case
    -- DHHClaimtype 04 needs to be broken out based on provider specialty and location
    When c.formtype = '1500' and Case When IsNumeric(cd.location) = 0 Then '' 
    Else cd.location End = 21 and ps.specialtycode in ('05','22','1T','1F','30','1C') then '04-Hospitalist'
    When c.formtype = '1500' 
    Then '04-Other'
    else '  '
 end as DHHClaimtype,
```